# Change the position of specific buttons at GtkHeaderBar?

Tags: python, gtk

I am creating a desktop recording program, I am designing the interface using Glade, and I am using GtkHeaderBar and client-side decoration.

This is what I have as an example: [Example interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBieV.png)

My question is: How can I move the about button - for example - to be after the title text, so that I get 3 buttons before the title, and 1 after it, just like GNOME applications?

I Googled and got to [gtk-decoration-layout](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-decoration-layout), but couldn't find a real way to use it (Seems it will be system-wide if used).

Comment: `gtk-decoration-layout` is for the minimize/maximize/close buttons. You want `pack_end()` instead of `pack_start()`. If you're using glade, it'll be under the Packing tab when you select the given child.

Comment: @andlabs Thank you, it worked well after using it, you could have put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gtk-decoration-layout` is for the minimize/maximize/close buttons. You want `pack_end()` instead of `pack_start()`. If you're using glade, it'll be under the Packing tab when you select the given child.